# Phonegap FileTransfer hangs on iOS (works on Android/WP8)

Tags: ios, file, cordova, file-transfer

We got a phonegap app that downloads some files to the local filesystem to make them available offline. This works fine on both Windows Phone 8 and Android. However when running the app on iOS it doesnt download the files and causes the app to hang.

This is our code to download the files:

```
    try {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
            fs.root.getDirectory(settings.filesRootDir, {
                create: true,
                exclusive: false
            }, function (directory) {
                var filePath = directory.toURL() + "/" + attachment.titleSanitized; // full file path
                console.log("filePath: " + filePath);
                var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

                fileTransfer.download(
                    url,
                    filePath,
                    function (entry) {
                        console.log("download complete entry to url: " + entry.toURL());
                        attachment.fileLocation = entry.toURL();

                        var attachments = ko.observableArray(store.get("attachments"), []);
                        attachments.push(attachment);
                        store.set("attachments", attachments());

                        defer.resolve();
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        console.log("download error code: " + error.code);
                        console.log("download error source: " + error.source);
                        console.log("download error target: " + error.target);
                        console.log("download error http_status: " + error.http_status);
                        defer.reject();
                    },
                    false,
                    {
                        headers: headers
                    });
            })
        }, function (error) {
            console.log("requestFileSystem error code: " + error.code);
            console.log("requestFileSystem error source: " + error.source);
            console.log("requestFileSystem error target: " + error.target);
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        alert(error.message);
    }
```

The console.log(filepath) shows:

```
cdvfile://localhost/persistent/ourapp//Aanvang.pdf
```

In the console of the iPHone Configuration Utility it shows:

```
<Warning>: File Transfer Finished with response code 200
<Warning>: void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (webView:resource:didFinishLoadingFromDataSource:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

And then it just waits and outputs that message every 10 seconds

I have a feeling that we're saving to the wrong path, but I'm not able to find any documentation or hints on where to save it. Note that this code works fine for Android/WP8.

Using:
Phonegap 3.4.0
org.apache.cordova.file 1.0.1
org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.4.2

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am seeing the same issue a year later